# How to configure certificates in a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, uwp, ssl-certificate, react-native-windows

I'm building a react-native-windows application using a visual studio project and trying to configure SSL certificates. I've been trying to do that using 'Package.appxmanifest' file at the 'Declerations' label.
[package.appmanifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGRp.png)

when running the app I'm still getting an invalid certificates error message.

I generated the certificates using the 'site information' in chrome browser: [generate certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmlib.png)

my question is:

1. Is there other way to configure SSL certifications in a visual studio project?
2. is there any other way to generate certificates for a certain site/API?

Comment: Do you want a cert for your *domain*, or for your app?

Comment: I want cert for the app that run on visual studio

Comment: That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing, different from SSL. You get code signing cert by purchasing one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate